# Error a la hora de conectar una base de datos a PYTHON

Tags: python, mysql-workbench

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='12341312312')

print(mydb)
```

este es el output que me da siempre:

```
raise errors.NotSupportedError(mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported
```

Cabe recalcar que utilizo MySQLworkbench y ya he probado distintas dependencias y no he tenido resultados.

Comment: Creo que estas usando el conector equivocado. Aca hay informacion al respecto en el foro en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50557234/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-is-not-supported

Comment: `MySQLworkbench` no es otra cosa que una interfaz gráfica para interactuar con la base de datos, a la cual puedes conectar desde diferentes partes, sean interfaces gráficas, sean lenguajes de programación, en cuyo caso debes preocuparte de tener los controladores adecuados y de usar el código correctamente, pasándole las credenciales correctas para conectar.